# tree properties on $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Are the following mutually consistent (relative to large cardinals)?

(1) There are no $\omega_2$-Aronszajn trees.

(2) There is an $\omega_1$-Kurepa tree.

In the models I know of the tree property at $\omega_2$, it also holds that there are no *weak* Kurepa trees on $\omega_1$ (also called Canadian trees).

Comment: What's a weak Kurepa tree?

Comment: It's a tree of height $\omega_1$ and levels of size at most $\omega_1$ with at least $\omega_2$ branches. Obviously they exist under CH.

Comment: Canadian trees?

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with set theorists from the University of Toronto...?

Comment: [This](https://books.google.com/books?id=2q_iBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA449&lpg=PA449&dq=baumgartner+canadian+tree&source=bl&ots=gWMlQxkp9M&sig=6_BcJy58nsSj028WiGNiyLUNwEY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBGoVChMIyvTNzeC7xwIVkYINCh3HYQAi#v=onepage&q=baumgartner%20canadian%20tree&f=false) says it is a pun too awful to mention.

Comment: Prof.Franklin Tall ,a set theorist at U of T , said it was, presumably ,called that because it was believed that they are what Canadian set theorists are  interested in.

Comment: K. McAloon showed that if there exists an $\omega_2$ Aronszajn tree then $\omega_2$ is Mahlo in $L$.(Godel's constructible class.)

Comment: Incorrect.  There is an $\omega_2$-Aronszajn tree in $L$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wrote a short note with the consistency proof, which can be found at http://www.math.cmu.edu/users/jcumming/papers/kurepa/kurepa.pdf. It is pretty rough, please tell me if there are problems.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your question is yes. During the "[IPM conference on set theory and model theory](http://math.ipm.ac.ir/conferences/2015/set_model_conf/)" James cummings gave me the basic idea of the proof of the following theorem:

**Theorem.** Assuming the existence of a weakly compact cardinal, it is consistent that there exists a Kurepa tree and tree property at $\aleph_2$
holds.

Comment: Though the proof is not really difficult, but I think it is better we wait for a published version of Cummings work.

Comment: Mohammad, thanks for this information.  Given that these publications usually take a long time to come out, could you post a rough sketch of the idea?

Comment: Any update? Does this use a new method for the tree property at $\omega_2$ or is the key a new method for forcing Kurepa trees?

Comment: @MonroeEskew I have no idea if there is preprint available, but the fact is that the proof if not really difficult. It is simply the product of Mitchell forcing  and (a modified version of the) forcing to add a Kurepa tree with $\kappa$-many branches, where $\kappa$ is the weakly compact we start at the beginning.

Comment: It seems like the hard part would be showing that the tree property on $\aleph_2$ is preserved.